# Program received signal SIGABRT error

Tags: xcode, wcf, rest

I'm developing an iPhone app in which I have to call a REST service from iPhone. I did it successfully and got the response successfully. But later I have changed the `xib` file so that I want to display the output on a label. Then after changing the `xib` file when I run the application I'm getting the following exception:

```
Program received signal SIGABRT
```

in the following code? Since I'm a beginner in iPhone development, I don't know how to fix this error. Here is my code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController; ///error at this line///
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

How to fix this error?
Thanks!

Comment: `SIGABRT` looks like an exception, what did you find in the error console?

Comment: Yes I got that exception at that line. Where should i check for error console? Later I deleted all the changes I made in xib file  eventhough getting the same exception ....

Comment: The precise kind of exception tells you what to do. The console is activated using Cmd-Shift-Y.

Comment: I got this:Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason:
    '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "IphonedevsdkViewController" nib 
      but the view outlet was not set.'

Answer (score 0):

In the `IphonedevsdkViewController` XIB you have to connect the topmost view to the `view` outlet of the File Owner.